# How do I use the .random module on a list to get a random item out without using .choice?

Tags: python, list, random

I'm a total begginer in programming :)

I'm trying to solve a coding challange which instructs me to
pick a random name out of a list but i'm not allowed to use the .choice function
instead I somehow need to pick an item out using the len() function
in my code.

```
# Split string method
names_string = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ")
names = names_string.split(", ")
#  Don't change the code above 

#Write your code below this line 
import random
```

Comment: Technically this would be OK: `print(random.choices(names)[0])`. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = names[random.randrange(len(names))]
```

This is also a possible solution:

```
result = names[random.randint(0, len(names) - 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access values in a list using their index. For example,

```py
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
# index     0 ,  1 ,  2

my_list[0] = "a"
```

`random.randint()` will pick a random integer from a range. You can use this to then select a random element of your list by index.